# How to bring default add user page at django custom admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When I use django's default admin page:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^admin/', include(django.contrib.admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The add user page looks pretty like this...
[image]

But when I use my own:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.stripe_admin_site.urls)),
)

class StripeAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
          return todo
```

and

> django.auth.contrib.models.User

registered to the site

```
stripe_admin_site.register(User)
```

I got this
[image]

Now how can I make it look like the default, easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply register the `User` model with the same [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) that Django uses by default:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
stripe_admin_site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```