# Created User from django custom admin page can't login

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a custom admin page:

```
class StripeAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
     ...
     pass
```

I have registered `django.contrib.auth.models` to this admin site:

```
stripe_admin_site = StripeAdminSite(name='Stripe')
stripe_admin_site.register(User)
```

Now User show up in the admin page, it also let me create users (as stuff), but after creation when I try to log in using them to dashboard it does not allow me to do that.

After switching back to default admin site, I got this written in my old users password fields:

> Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.

[image]

Now what can be done?

More/Extra information: [How to bring default add user page at django custom admin page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507402/how-to-bring-default-add-user-page-at-django-custom-admin-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you did not register the `User` model with Django's `UserAdmin`. This means that the password was not hashed properly when the user was created, so they can't log in.

To use Django's `UserAdmin`, change your code as follows.

```
stripe_admin_site = StripeAdminSite(name='Stripe')
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
stripe_admin_site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Once you have done this, you will not get this problem for new users that you add in future.

Use the **change password** link to reset the password for any existing users, and then they should be able to log in.